# Sound problem - no output device detected

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 and can't make the sound work - have been trying for good ten hours. I am a linux newbie so I will appreciate any help.
This is how my sound settings look like, there is no output and the slider is gray.

The speakers are internal and headphones are connected via the aux cable - sound is coming out from none of them. There is however no hardware issue with the headphones, they work perfectly when connected to a phone, and I don't expect any hardware problem with the internal speakers.

[image: This]

I followed the advices such as unmute the AlsaMixer master, but I can't see it at all:

[image: picture]

```
sudo aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0


lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9d71 (rev 21)
  Subsystem: Dell Device 0786
  Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 16
    Memory at d5228000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at d5200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl

uname -r
    4.13.0-36-generic
```

It seems this might be the problem, but I have no idea what should I do next:

```
dmesg | grep snd_hda_intel
  [    3.286909] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
  [    5.166250] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
  [    8.212134] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: azx_get_response timeout, switching to polling mode: last cmd=0x000f0000 
  [    9.220171] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, disabling MSI: last cmd=0x000f0000
  [   10.224131] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: Codec #0 probe error; disabling it...
```

My notebook is Dell Vostro 5568.
Thank you for any of your suggestions!

Comment: Which kernel version are you using? In 16.04, it's likely to be older than your hardware.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I made the changes you wanted, hope it is ok now.

Comment: @CL. Does it mean I need the most recent version?

Comment: Probably; try upgrading both the kernel and linux-firmware packages.

Comment: The kernel appears to be the most recent version already. Did you install the `linux-firmware` package? What's the output of `dmesg | grep snd_hda_intel`?

Comment: `linux-firmware` is at the latest version. I added the output of `dmesg | grep snd_hda_intel` to the problem description, seems this might be it, but what to do next?

Comment: Odd - when I load windows (dualboot) the sound does not work either. Same problem, no output device detected.